# How to edit path for django unit tests?

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to run the standard 'python manage.py test` however I'm getting a:

```
`ImportError: No module named 'draft1.app'` for all 9 of my apps in my project (9 errors).
```

Full error example:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: draft1.profiles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'draft1.profiles'
```

My project tree is:

```
/draft1
    /draft1
    /profiles 
    ...    
    /bin
    /lib
    /include
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are calling the unit tests from, you'll need to back up and add the main folder to the path.

Try adding this to the top of your unit test file.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
```

If your unit tests are two levels deep, then try this... etc

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
```

Comment: Do you mean put that in my `draft1.app/test.py?`

Comment: Be sure to put it before the `from draft1.profiles...`